# Android: MVP: Can presenter/model contain Android Context?

Tags: android, mvp

I implemented the MVP pattern and it's working fine.

My understanding:

1. **Presenter** must not contain any Android code
2. **Model** must not contain any Android code

As result I can mock **View** and test **Presenter** and **Model** independently.

Is my understanding correct? Can **Presenter** and **Model** contain/reference `android.content.Context` ?

Comment: what do you need the context for ? And what Context would you pass ?

Comment: I need context to get file from application cache dir. Something like this:  `public static File getAppCacheDir(Context context) {
        return context.getCacheDir();
    }` And method `getAppCacheDir(Context context)` I put to Model.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39100105/need-context-in-model-in-mvp